# Is there a way i can program an App that executes predefined gestures and movements?

Tags: java, android

I want the App to have predefined gestures like: goOnline(); that opens WhatsApp,
then click on the first chat, read the message and reply with a Dialogflow Interaction.

Yet, i did find something about WhatsApp not having an API and not letting it do things with it Programmatically, so i want to have an app that runs in the background or the foreground, that just controls the phone itself with gestures that do that for me.
Phone battery or having the screen on forever isn't a Problem. It will always be On and Charging.

For example, goOnline(); just draws upwards from the bottom, opening the App Drawer.
Then it clicks on the App that is pre-defined with coordinates, then opens the first chat, once again, with coordinates. Then click on the bottom chat field so the keyboard opens, write something random (Dialogflow) Then answer by pressing the enter key to and then go back to the Chat overview (pressing the back button at the top left) Close WhatsApp again by pressing the home button at the bottom.

**Now my actual question and tl;dr:**
Can i make scripted paths like swiping and clicking in Android Studio with coordinates and build them into functions?
 I hope someone can help.

Comment: In general, Android will block your app because it tries to control other apps. Usually this is security issue. E.g. imagine if your app was sitting in background while you were doing your online banking - it would be able to intercept your passwords and read your balances

Comment: it will never be on the play store and the phone this will run on has been rooted, will it still not work?